# How to test catch-part of the method?

Tags: apex, soql, unit-test, query, list

I tried to put null rows and do many another things. I can't test this catch. It writes `System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject`.

```
public List<MyObject__c> getList(){
    try{
        myList = [SELECT Id, Name, Title__c FROM MyObject__c];
    } catch(QueryException e){
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Query error:  ' + e.getMessage()));  
    }
    return myList;
}
```

Comment: it throws `QueryException` and you catch `QueryException`. So what is a problem?

Comment: are you writing a test class? If yes, please update your question with further details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `myList` is typed as a `List<MyObject__c>`, you should never get the error

> System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

That error arises when you assign a query result directly to a single sObject, as in

```
Contact c = [SELECT Id FROM Contact];
```

and the query result does not contain exactly one record. That is, zero or more than one resulting record will throw the `QueryException`.

Since your method returns a list, if this code compiles, it won't throw that specific exception.

You should simply remove the `try`/`catch` block here, because you're not going to catch any errors and you can't create an error condition to cover the `catch` block.